# How to convert java timestamp to php timestamp?

Tags: java, php, timestamp

how can I convert a Java timestamp like this one `1335997853142` to a format that php can read?
`1335997853142` should be `02 May 2012 22:30:53`.

But what ever I try I get errors or PHP says `1970-01-01 01:00:00` or `2038-01-19 04:14:07`

PLS help!!! I'm searching for over 1.5h for a soloution!

Comment: Use `java.util.Calendar`. That's all you get for this great question.

Comment: Java timestamp is milliseconds from linux time, php is seconds from linux time. Divide java time by 1000 to get php time.

Comment: @Torious: dont want to use java - i'm converting 1220 values from a xml file with php to mysql

Answer (score 8):

PHP timestamps are seconds, not milliseconds.

```
echo gmdate("d M Y H:i:s",1335997853);
```

That outputs `02 May 2012 22:30:53`.

Comment: damn it!! ok, now works - with all of your soloutions! thx!!

problem was: the string has spaces (dont know why!). after a trim() everything worked.

sorry guys but thank you all!

Answer (score 6):

it is not a java timestamp, it is milliseconds since [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29#Computing) (1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT)

Which [php supports too](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) except in seconds so the following should work in php:

```
date('choose your format', javaMilliseconds / 1000);
```

Comment: as Mark Reed says also date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

Answer (score 2):

Date/Time: April / 08 / 2014 12:17:42pm UTC

Java timestamp: 1396959462222

PHP timestamp: 1396959462

Dividing by 1000 doesn't give exactly the right answer because it will give a double or float value, i.e. 1396959462.222 which is not what we want. We need an integer here like 1396959462. So correct way to convert Java timestamp to PHP timestamp would be by using intval():

```
$php_timestamp = intval($java_timestamp/1000);
```

In a real example, in one of my Android apps where I send Java timestamp to a PHP server, I do it as mentioned above. Also, for good security practice, I add a preg_replace() to make sure if someone added hack code in this field, it is removed:

```
$php_timestamp = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $java_timestamp)/1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Java gives you a timestamp in milliseconds. PHP uses Unix seconds, so divide by 1000:

```
  print(date("r", 1335997853142/1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp you have is in milliseconds when it should be in seconds

```
$java_time = 1335997853142;
$php_time = $java_time / 1000;
$today = date("d M Y G:i:s", $php_time);
```

Output

```
02 May 2012 22:30:53
```

Comment: this gives for all values in the array: 25 Jan 1970 20:31:23

Comment: I was missing some semicolons, fixed now

Comment: Are you sure you are retrieving the entries from xml properly?

Answer (score 1):

date need a timestamp in integer format. So I think U should remove 3 last number. Not use division beause it will return float number.

Answer (score 0):

Use the date() function in php, the parameters are found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

It's a timestamp in microtime

Use

```
$time = date("whatever you need", $javatime / 1000);
```

Comment: i used this:
date('Y-m-d H:i:s',  $values['date'] / 1000); // 1970-01-25 21:31:23
this:
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (int) $values['date'] / 1000) // 1970-01-25 21:31:23
this:
date('U = Y-m-d H:i:s', (int) $values['date']) // 2038-01-19 04:14:07
this:
date('U = Y-m-d H:i:s', (int) $values['date']) // Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long

wtf is wrong?!?